# Stored Procedure Insert (Select and Values)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm looking to have a stored procedure that will:

- run through Table A and retrieve all IDs.
- insert into Table B all IDs (loop) but also static values which aren't found in Table A.

How do I approach this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST AS 
BEGIN

select ID from TABLE A;


INSERT INTO TABLE B
    (
    created_date,
    created_by,
    ID
    )
VALUES ('sysdate', '1', 'RESULTS FROM SELECT QUERY');
END TEST;
```

Not sure how to merge static data ('sysdate' and '1') with results from a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for 2 separate queries.  This should work with `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB
    (
    created_date,
    created_by,
    ID
    )
SELECT 'sysdate', '1', id
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: Having 'sysdate' and '1' not be existing data in TABLEA will not be a problem? Is that all that is required, wrap static data between quotes?

Comment: @Alex -- That won't be a problem, but the quotes might.  It depends on the data type of the columns you are selecting into.  You may not be intending on wrapping sysdate in quotes for example if that is a date field.  Same with the value 1, if that's an int.  Instead use something like `select sysdate, 1, id from tablea`.

Comment: Thanks. One last question, this will loop through for the amount of returned id's from TableA?

Comment: Correct, restrict the WHERE clause if you need to narrow down the users